# Mysql match query problem

Tags: sql, mysql

Natural Language Full-Text Searches
I use the mysql Match function. What's wrong with it?

```
$ititle = wp_title('',0,'');


$query = mysql_query("SELECT posttitle, posturl, siteurl MATCH (posttitle, posturl, siteurl) AGAINST $ititle AS score FROM interlinks WHERE MATCH (posttitle, posturl, siteurl) AGAINST $ititle AND title <> $ititle");
```

TY

Comment: I don't know, what IS wrong with it?

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: Did you enable fulltext indexes on the table ?  (This is usually the problem when people ask about full text searches)

Comment: @Stephen: I've seen problems with certain versions where mysql would oopsing and you get no results without using an index (usually when the dataset is really large).  Thats why I'm just inquiring if he is using indexes

Comment: @suberfro: redacted.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, here is the code:

```
$ititle = wp_title('',0,'');


$query = mysql_query("SELECT posttitle, posturl, siteurl, MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('$ititle') AS score FROM interlinks WHERE MATCH (posttitle,posturl,siteurl) AGAINST ('$ititle')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parentheses and quotation marks around the variable in the `AGAINST` conditions.

```
AGAINST ('$ititle')
```

Comment: still no:( SELECT posttitle, posturl, siteurl MATCH (posttitle, posturl) AGAINST ('$ititle') AS score FROM interlinks WHERE MATCH (posttitle, posturl) AGAINST ('$ititle') AND title <> '$ititle'

Comment: show me this right after the query:  `echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";`